# nested cards, fitting cards within a card - bootstrap cards

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-cards

I am trying to do **nested cards** in my project, so basically I have three cards. The parent one `Research Dashboard`, the second one which holds the category ex. `Recently Added Research` and lastly, the third one or the `third card` which contains the image/card title and button. However, I am getting trouble when viewing it on a mobile browser. As you can see in the image the third card stretches up until the first card which is I do not like, the third card should only go to the second card which is `Recently Added Research`.

I've tried readjusting the width of the cards, but it gets destroy whenever I view it on the desktop browser which is I do not like.

[image]

```
<style>
        .card {
            /* Add shadows to create the "card" effect */
            box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            transition: 0.3s;
            margin: 0 auto;
            float: none;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }

        /* On mouse-over, add a deeper shadow */
        .card:hover {
            box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        }

        body {
            background-color: #003366;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid" style="padding-top: 50px;">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header text-center " style="font-family: Sans-Serif; text-transform:uppercase; font-size:1.5rem">
                Research Dashboard
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="container-fluid" style="padding-top: 50px;">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">
                            <div class="card  h-100">
                                <div class="card-header text-center " style="font-family: Sans-Serif; text-transform:uppercase; font-size:1.5rem">
                                    Recently Added Research
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col">
                                            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                                                <img class="card-img-top" src="admin/files/Images/pagenotfound.png" alt="Card image cap">
                                                <div class="card-body">
                                                    <h5 class="card-title text-center">Card title</h5>
                                                    <button class="btn btn-info justify-content-start">View </button>
                                                    <button class="btn btn-info align-items-end">View </button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col">
                                            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                                                <img class="card-img-top" src="admin/files/Images/pagenotfound.png" alt="Card image cap">
                                                <div class="card-body">
                                                    <h5 class="card-title text-center">Library Management System</h5>
                                                    <p class="card-text">Date added: <span>May 23, 2021</span></p>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>  
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is my ideal result. However, this image was a screenshot in desktop view.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```css
.card {
            /* Add shadows to create the "card" effect */
            box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            transition: 0.3s;
            margin: 0 auto;
            float: none;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }

        /* On mouse-over, add a deeper shadow */
        .card:hover {
            box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        }

        body {
            background-color: #003366;
        }
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid" style="padding-top: 50px;">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header text-center " style="font-family: Sans-Serif; text-transform:uppercase; font-size:1.5rem">
            Research Dashboard
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="container-fluid" style="padding-top: 50px;">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="card  h-100">
                            <div class="card-header text-center " style="font-family: Sans-Serif; text-transform:uppercase; font-size:1.5rem">
                                Recently Added Research
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col">
                                        <div class="card" style="max-width: 18rem;">
                                            <img class="card-img-top" src="admin/files/Images/pagenotfound.png" alt="Card image cap">
                                            <div class="card-body">
                                                <h5 class="card-title text-center">Card title</h5>
                                                <button class="btn btn-info justify-content-start">View </button>
                                                <button class="btn btn-info align-items-end">View </button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col">
                                        <div class="card" style="max-width: 18rem;">
                                            <img class="card-img-top" src="admin/files/Images/pagenotfound.png" alt="Card image cap">
                                            <div class="card-body">
                                                <h5 class="card-title text-center">Library Management System</h5>
                                                <p class="card-text">Date added: <span>May 23, 2021</span></p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Got it, u used max-width for the cards. Thank you.